# Calculating rate constant of intersystem crossing from Jablonski diagram

Tags: physical-chemistry, photochemistry

I am to calculate the rate constant for $T_1 \to S_0$ intersystem crossing, with reference to the Jablonski diagram attached below. I know this should not be difficult, but for some reason I cannot put the number together to get the correct result.

I have that

$$
\Phi_\text{ISC} = \frac{k_\text{ISC}}{\sum_i k_i}
$$

where the denominator represents a sum of all decay pathways for the $T_1$ state. However, how can this sum be calculated if we do not know the rate constants to begin with?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The lifetime of the excited state is the reciprocal of the sum of rate constants which you are trying to find:

$$\begin{align}
\tau(T_1) = \frac{1}{\sum_i k_i(T_1)} &= \pu{6 \times 10^-3 s} \\
\sum_i k_i(T_1) &= \frac{1}{\pu{6 \times 10^-3 s}} \\
&= \pu{167 s^-1}
\end{align}$$

The two lines going from the $T_1 \to S_0$ state represent intersystem crossing (ISC) and phosphorescence. Squiggly lines represent nonradiative transitions, of which ISC is one, so the quantum yield for ISC is 10%. (Straight lines represent radiative transitions, in this case phosphorescence.)

Therefore:

$$\begin{align}
k_\text{ISC} &= \Phi_\text{ISC} \cdot \sum_i k_i(T_1) \\
&= 0.1 \cdot \pu{167 s^-1} \\
&= \pu{16.7 s^-1}
\end{align}$$